# React Router 5 with Meteor: how to ignore files in /public

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router

I have an application running React with React Router 5 being served by Meteor.  I have some static assets in the Meteor `/public` directory like so:

```
/css/pageName.css
/css/common.css
```

I have the pages mounted in the following manner:

```
const LocaleSwitch = () => {
  const { locale } = useParams();
  const match = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={ `${match.path}/pageName` }>
        <PageName locale={locale}/>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  )
};

const App = (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/:locale">
      <LocaleSwitch/>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
);
```

When I request `/css/common.css`, I get the file as expected.  However, when I request `/css/pageName.css`, I get pageName with a locale of 'css' instead of the intended file.  Is there some way to improve this app to get the desired result?  The obvious solution would be to just rename pageA.css to something else, but this isn't ideal and it would be problematic for developers to remember this convention.

It would be great if one of these solutions was possible:

1. Configure Meteor to try to return static files in `/public` before trying to render the React Router.
2. Only mount `LocalizedSwitch` if `:locale` matches a particular regex
3. An acceptable solution would be to configure React Router to ignore any path ending in `.css`.

Are any of these possible?

Comment: How are you requesting `/css/pageName.css` in your code?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet/css" href="/css/pageName.css"/>` within a `<Helmet/>`

Comment: It sounds like `useParams()` is returning `{locale: "css", ...}`, which it shouldn't do. Presumably this is the React Router 5 method you are calling. Have you checked for RR5 bugs in this area?

Comment: @Mikkel - why shouldn't it return that?  That seems expected to me for the route `<Route path="/:locale">`.  That route should interpret the first path param as 'locale' no matter what the string is.